# How to extend my contact form to main page?

Tags: html, django

I'm trying to extend my contact.html which contains contact form to my 'home.html' which acts as base.html. But it's not working and I tried many ways yet not working. Basically, the form not appearing on home.html when it suppose to be. However, it appears as usual on localhost:8000/contact.
My code are as following.

Home.html

```
<section id="contact-us" class="section">

  <div class="main-contact">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="contact">
        <h2>LET US HELP YOU</h2>
        <p> Push the boundaries of efficiency and excellence through game changing solutions.<br>
            We provide innovative solutions that combine international best practices with cutting edge technology for finaciers, governments and property professionals.<br>
            Speak to us or email us at info@resolutions.com.my today about how we can help your organisation get ahead.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form">

        <h3>FILL UP THE FORM BELOW FOR MORE INFORMATION ABOUT VALUATION MANAGEMENT SYSTEM</h3>
        <div id="active">
           <li><a href='{% url "contact.html" %}'></a></li>
          {% block content %}

          {% endblock %}

        </div>

          </a></li>



      </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

contact.html

```
{% extends "home.html" %}
{% load envelope_tags %}


{% block default-active %}active{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="{% url 'envelope-contact' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% antispam_fields %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Send!" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

added my views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from re_web.forms import ContactForm

# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import (
    TemplateView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView,
    ListView,
    DetailView,
)
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from re_web.models import Article

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    def contact(request):
        form_class = ContactForm

        return render(request, 'contact.html', {
            'form': form_class,
        }
```

)

Comment: What do you mean its not working? What is the error message? What do you see on the screen?

Comment: basically, the form not appearing on home.html when it suppose to be. However, it appears as usual on localhost:8000/contact.

Comment: Do you include the `form` context variable in your home view too? Post your `home` view.

Comment: Its not appearing on `home.html` because you are loading it on `contact.html`, and its not supposed to load on `home.html` either, since that's the base template. If you want it to appear there, then  you'll have to render `home.html` with the form in its context, or create a custom template tag and render the form in `home.html`. Right now, everything is working as it should.

Comment: added views. @Selcuk